# 魅力的って言われてもお前だって困る in this context

Tags: parsing

> girl「まさかお前っ……こ、こここの胸が私の魅力だと言いたいのか！？」
>
> mc「誰もそんなこと言ってないだろ！？」
>
> girl「…………」
>
> mc「ああ違う、魅力的じゃないとも言ってない！　いやすごい！　お前の胸はすごいよ！」
>
> **mc「でもそんなの魅力的って言われてもお前だって困るだろ！？」**

uh no, i'm not saying that your boobs don't have appeal, rather they're amazing, your boobs are amazing!

but even if (I am) saying that's your appeal, you are troubled too?

i'm not sure what the MC is trying to claim in the last sentence, from the girls initial reaction it's obvious she doesn't liker her boobs being her 魅力.

thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A fairly literal translation might be something like:

> But even if you were told that was attractive, you'd be bothered right!?

In parts:

> そんなの(が)魅力的って言われても

Literally `Even if you were told something like that (of yours) was attractive`. The use of `そんなの` here is just to emphasize that the topic, `胸`, is in a genre of things that one likely wouldn't want to be complemented on.

> お前だって困る

`だって` is sometimes hard to translate literally, but this would be something like `Even you'd be bothered` or `You'd be bothered too`. I would lean toward the latter because it does a good job capturing the fact that the MC outright complementing a girl on her chest would presumably be awkward for both of them.

A fairly interpreted but more natural English translation might be something like:

> But that's not the kind of thing you want to be complemented on anyway, right?!

Comment: Woops, didn't realize 魅力的 was referencing すごい. All good now

Comment: ...you mean that 魅力的 was referencing 胸？

Comment: Isn't he backtracking his alternate way of putting it (すごい)?

Comment: I see, you mean that 魅力的 is in some sense standing in for すごい here, and he's backtracking. That's certainly a valid interpretation. You can also look at it as "すごい" being sufficiently vague that he can get away with it, but 魅力的 being too forward. Getting into distinctions too minute to be useful though.

Comment: Yeah, すごい as a 魅力的 way of saying her boobs are her  魅力 point.  Though that may not line up grammatically now that I look at it

Comment: すごい could frankly mean any number of things. I think (as above) you can look at this two ways. Either the すごい was intended to imply 魅力的 and he’s now backtracking with something along the lines of “but you wouldn’t be happy to hear that anyway”, or he is of the opinion that すごい was vague enough to be a safe thing to say, but that 魅力的 is too forward. I was thinking the latter, but it also doesn’t change much either way. 
Also, I see we both have the same problem of accidentally hitting enter while typing our comments.